# Delete element in list

Tags: python

I have a master list which regroups every ID I have.

```
master = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Among all of these ID, I want to exclude some of them. So I did a second list of ID which have to be exclude

```
exclude = [1, 4, 5]
```

In your opinion, what is the good operation to make for having :

```
master_exclude = [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If you know what I mean ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you try anything before asking this question?

Comment: @wwii Thank you! I was searching for a duplicate too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This conditional [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will work:

```
master_exclude = [x for x in master if x not in exclude]
```

If these involved lists are larger, consider first converting `exclude` to a `set` in order to make the contains check more performant:

```
exclude = set(exclude)
```

Comment: No effort made from OP. Maybe it was a homework.

Comment: @ElisByberi: Please show me a link/text that stackoverflow has a problem with prorgamming homeworks??!!!

Comment: @DRPK https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions I will have agree ElisByberi  that the OP did not show any effort of his own.

Comment: Not at all. I'm programing only for fun ! I'm learning the Framework Django and I had an issue about something.

Comment: @DRPK I do not want to, neither I can stop you from doing others' homeworks. Do what you want to do. I have the right to express my opinions.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: i know bro ... but i have a question... why did you answer him?! and that is not a original internal stackoverflow privac_policy link! thats just another question link with a lot of people's personal opinions...so?!

Comment: @ElisByberi: i know what you mean....but stackoverflow is for everyone..such as kids and students..we can not force them to just ask a highlevel questions ..man!

Comment: @ElisByberi Wound point... one could argue to provide a correct answer knowing remove- and pop- based solutions will be suggested. But at the end of the day, I don't mind helping out and this question is quick'n'easy rep ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to make the most simple question for a better understanding and occult any non important information. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with a simple for loop.

```
master = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

exclude = [1, 4, 5]

for o in exclude:
    try:
        master.remove(o)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(master) # [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: If you set `master = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` then after running this, only the first `1` will be removed: `[1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: Thanks to pointing it out. !!

Answer (score 1):

The `list-comprehension` is definitely the right way to go, but this can also be done with `filter`. Not the ideal solution, but is another thought:

```
master_exclude = list(filter(lambda i: i not in exclude, master))
```

which gives:

```
[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

Or you could use a `while` and `for-loop`:

```
for i in exclude:
    while master.count(i) > 0:
        master.remove(i)
```

which gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the element from the `master` list, which are in `exclude`

```
for i in exclude:
    master.remove(i)
```

Will not remove duplicates.

Comment: It will work fine if all the elements of `exclude` belongs to the `master` list. Other wise it will lead to `ValueError`

Comment: ... and `remove` is an `O(N)` operation which makes this approach `O(N*M)` which is why it is better to build the new list from scratch.

Comment: @SreeramTP agree! thanks!

Comment: @schwobaseggl thanks! you answered list comprehension, so..

Comment: @schwobaseggl wouldn't using a `list-comprehension` also be `O(n*m)` as testing `not in` still has to go through the `exclude` `list`. Of course it would depend on the relative sizes of the `lists`...

Comment: @JoeIddon True, that's why I added the set conversion remark... which would make the comprehension  `O(M+N)`